# How to speeding up the scaling process in python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a large text dataset and I'm using the `MinMaxScaler` to transform one feature. The code is working fine but takes more than 3 mins and I want to reduce the consumed time for this process. Is there any suggestions to speed up this process OR alternative method to so this transformation faster?

```
df = cleanData('data.csv')
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 5))
scaler.fit(pd.DataFrame(df.loc[:,'year']))
df.loc[:,'year'] = scaler.transform(pd.DataFrame(df.loc[:,'year']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing it with `dask-ml`:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask_ml.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# or read directly from csv with ddf = dd.read_csv('data.csv')
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 5))
scaler.fit(ddf['year'])
ddf['year'] = scaler.transform(ddf['year'])
```

There are also other preprocessing tools available in `dask_ml`, see https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html?highlight=minmaxscaler

Comment: Hi, I get this error ruuning your code: AttributeError: 'Scalar' object has no attribute 'copy'
Do you have any idea?